# PHP / Postgre Problem on Mac

Tags: mac, php, postgresql

Hey there, I'm on a project that uses drupal and postgresql, and i was developing using console and ssh, but i had some troubles and i want to make it local. So i enabled mac's Apache and PHP, and everything went fine, but then i installed pgsql and i had trouble, as it wouldn't work, since mac's php doesn't have support for pg. I copied a phppgadmin on my Sites folder, and when i access it, Safari shows an error taht says: "Your php installation doesn't support PostgreSQL. Please compile again using --with-pgsql" (just translated it, it's something like that since my mac is portuguese-br). Then i installed the Entropy PHP, i did comment the line on httpd that used mac's original php as they say on the installation guide. But it didn't work, i wrote a test.php and safari wouldn't show it, i restarted Apache, but even with this it wouldn't show up.

Now i need some new ideas. I'm downloading phppgadmin and Apache from stackbuilder from the Postgre applications and see what it does, maybe it "catches" the Entropy PHP and uses it, as it has the pgsql module.

What happened to my Entropy PHP that isn't working as it should? probably Apache isn't using it's libraries, and i don't have an idea of how to do this since i'm new to web programming.

Entropy's website is this one:
http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/

and they don't say to uncomment this line after the instalation:

`#LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

so i think the installation went wrong, but i didn't see any error.

edit AGAIN:

gave up on Entropy PHP, apparently it doesn't work on Leopard, so i have to stick to Apple's PHP implementation, now I'm searching the easiest way to enable pgsql support. i tried this one:

discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10524084

but when i run the "phpize" command, i get some strange errors and can't move on.
maybe ill have to install macports, well.. let's see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Found a way to make drupal, php and pgsql happen on MAC, after a long search and almost downloading the source for apache and php and compile 'em up, found this "hidden" package which includes everything i need:

http://bitnami.org/stack/mappstack

Google shows a lot of stuff that's not related to this if you search.
It's pretty much like a windows installation, just keep clicking next and it works like a charm.